# Custom GridView Adaptor Android

Tags: gridview, horizontallistview

I am working on custom grid view so inside adaptor I have added horizontal listview and I am creating a loop to create horizontal list but it works only for single count whenever I click on button then below code is calling
    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(
                                getActivity(), R.layout.academic_grid, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
it's creating only one item inside the horizontal list and when I scroll down grid view it automatically adding more items inside my horizontal list. Can anyone solve my problem ?